# Weatherstack API keeps timing out for me when using VS Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, backend, etimedout

So, I was making a simple weather app, and decided that I will use Weatherstack API to get the weather information, I signed up, tried the API from the browser (sometimes it works perfectly, sometimes it takes very long time and basically times out)
But 95% of the times I try to run the same code from VSCode, it times out giving me the below error message:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT *myIP*:80
        at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16) {
      errno: -60,
      code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
      syscall: 'connect',
      address: '*myIP*',
      port: 80
    }
```

And the 5% left, it actually works and gives the correct results as tried from the browser.
So, I am 100% it's NOT in my code!

Does someone know if that's some connection/firewall issue?

As mentioned above, I tried running it from browser, works like 9 times out of 10
But from VSCode, works like 1 time out of 20